# What is a legal way to use music from registered authors in a game?

Tags: game-industry, music, copyright

I have recently asked a [question about music in games like Guitar Hero.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42192/guitar-hero-clone-and-music/42200#comment71777_42200)

I have found that that in Europe (at least) if I do want to use a track composed by a musician member of a royalty collecting society I need to pay a flat fee to the society and not only to the member.

So a "one-to-one" agreement is not valid and the society can come up to me and ask me for money for each download. Even if for FREE!

This is a fee sheet list of the UK agency:
[for fee, see "Permanent download services"](http://www.prsformusic.com/users/broadcastandonline/onlinemobile/MusicServices/LOML/Pages/LOML.aspx)

It is about 1,200 GBP for less than 22,000 copies and they DON'T specify anything more and they said me on the phone that **I need to wait and see how many downloads I get before knowing the price.**

This is kind of crazy as If I give away the App for free I will have to PAY 1,200 GBP!!

I am shocked and I feel very bad.

The other solution is to work only with non registered musicians.

The question here to you is:

Has anyone found a legal way to use music from registered authors in a game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the artist has entered into an agreement with a royalties collection agency - whether for the recording, or the songwriting - then you can't use their music without a licence from the relevant agency or agencies in order to use the music. This is because the artist has assigned their rights to the collection agency, and is no longer legally allowed to give you a separate licence to use the work.

In theory, the artist and the collection agency could negotiate individual exceptions. In practice, this won't happen. The reason collections agencies exist is to make it easier for everybody - without them, each artist would have to talk to each venue or business to get their royalties. With a collections agency, the artist only has to deal with one organisation, and so do the venues and businesses. If the agency then had to keep track of each individual direct agreement between artists and 3rd parties, the job of collecting and distributing revenues would be much more complex.

Your only options are these:

- buy a licence for yourself
- work as part of an organisation that already has a licence
- work exclusively with artists who have not transferred their rights to a collections agency

Comment: I'd say this is technically mostly false, but a very useful answer nonetheless. You can't summarise all relevant copyright and related laws in two paragraphs with any decent accuracy, but doing things legally and not getting into legal trouble are two different things. Upsetting copyright agencies is a minefield you probably want to stay away from.

Comment: I agree. No technical issues here, but solely legal. I am an indie game developer at my first project, so I am looking at things under all aspects for the first time. From artwork IP to music licenses. Some lawyers proposed me a "getting away" from troubles way on the music license which didn't give me 100% guarantess and hence I think the answer above summarizes by current solution. I am also trying to understand how the license in http://freesound.org/ works, as apparently from the answer before, if an author registered to a society wouldn't be able to license a sound using that site.

Comment: @Marcks Thomas - if you think it's false, then post another answer or corrections as comments. As far as I am aware, in jurisdictions that have collections agencies and have laws in line with the Berne Convention, the situation works as I have described it.

Comment: @Kylotan: For instance: "If the artist has entered into an agreement with a royalties collection agency [...] then you can't use their music". That's not true, but saying you *can* use their music without going into far more detail with regard to the applicable exceptions and restrictions than is within the scope of this site, would probably make the answer actually less useful. I wanted to point that out as a warning not to take this advice out of context.

Comment: If you have any specific examples of exceptions then the original poster would be very grateful to hear them. In my experience once the rights are transferred the collections agency will not permit any use without a licence. Obviously each jurisdiction may have fair use policies or exceptions to copyright law but it's highly unlikely any of them will apply to a commercial game.

Comment: @MarcksThomas I agree with Kylotan, if you have any examples please share. I am aware that in the U.S. there is the compulsory mechanical licensing law, that for instance is the reason for which youtube users can post covers of original songs with only that simple and easy to get license, but doesn't cover soundtracks (as far as is written here http://easysonglicensing.com/Pages/About/Copyright%20Law/Compulsory%20Law.aspx) and is only for "personal purpose" so not our commercial game case. However, I contacted the PRS agency and another one (SIAE) and both have no specific license for Apps.

Comment: Hence SIAE said that they will get back to me in 2 weeks time (hopefully) and PRS proposed a too high price that I cannot afford (there is a limitation on the nr. of downloads and no certainity on the next band). In synthesis, the simpler way to do music for a indie game legally is not to deal with any registered musician. Again, using freesounds.org might be theoretically dangerous as there might be authors enrolled in societies that license the song by attribution (Creative commons) without realizing that their agreement with the society doesn't allow them to to so. Hence you could

Comment: *could theoretically find an agency knocking at your door for some fees (if ur indie game will be popular enough to raise to their attention, which might be 1% of the cases).

Comment: @Kylotan: Okay, an example, which probably does not apply to mm24, but is just one out of many. If you and the author had agreed on terms for commercial exploitation of his music while he was still entitled to do so, but gave up those rights in contract to a collective agency that now forbids it, you retain the rights previously agreed upon, because an agreement between musician and agency cannot affect the rights of non-parties.

Comment: @MarcksThomas: That exception may exist, but my answer is phrased in such a way that we're talking about a situation where the rights have already been transferred. (eg. the term 'no longer'.) But even so, the agreement with the agency can require you to terminate past licences as a precondition, as it's impossible to agree to transfer exclusive rights if you no longer have them yourself. This may be a legal problem for the artist rather than the licensee.

Comment: @MarcksThomas I agree completely with what Kylotan says. In my contract with non-agencies artist I have a specific condition about this and I've included a way to terminate the contract in case the musician wants to join a agency in the future.